# Powershell Script Recursion Error

Tags: function, powershell, recursion

Currently running into a strange error with a Powershell Function

Here's the code:

```
import-module ActiveDirectory
function Reset-Passwords{  

#Imports csv containing user details. The column names indicate the property type of the values in each row.
$users = import-CSV -path "C:\Users\administrator\Desktop\Powershell\Scripts\NQSMoves\NQS\NQSDetails.csv"
$SamAccountNames = $Users | select sAMAccountName

$password = Convertto-SecureString -string "228Hamilton" -asPlainText -force 


foreach($SamAccountName in $SamAccountName){
    set-adAccountPassword -identity $SamAccountName -reset -newPassword $password
}


}
Reset-Passwords
```

When run, it outputs the error:

```
The script failed due to call depth overflow. The call depth reached 1001 and the maximum is 1000.
```

From what I've gathered, this is a recursion error.

However there are only 26 '$samAccountName' variables so the foreach loop should only run 26 times? The csv file itself only has 26 rows so this should limit the foreach loop.

This is just one part of a bigger AD administration script and it's the only part that's giving issues.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is this the correct code, shouldn't it be 
foreach($SamAccountName in $SamAccountNames)

Comment: The list your iterating over isn't what you think it is. That could be contributing to the problem.

Comment: Plus I do not see any recursion in the code

Comment: Sorry, I must have deleted the 's' in $SamAccountName while copying over the code by mistake.
Even with the change that Lachie White sugggested below, the recursion error is still occuring

Comment: `import-module ActiveDirectory` ... and your file is called ActiveDirectory.ps1? or folder name, or similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As superblygeneralobject, stated. If that is indeed the code you are executing you are currently loop repetitively.

I would simplify make the following change to your script:

```
ForEach($SamAccountName in $Users.SamAccountName){
....
}
```

This would allow you to get rid of the `$SamAccountNAmes = $Users | select sAMAccountName` line of code you have.

It would also fix the issue you have where the code is looping itself

Hope This Helps

Comment: I closed and reopened Powershell ISE.
Now it says that the set-ADAccountPassword cannot accept a $null argument at -identity.